# Laravel rest api JWT-auth обработка ошибок

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel5, jwt

Доброго времени суток! Розбираюсь с Рест АПІ на Laravel, и чесно говоря зашел уже голова от всего этого болит. С принципами розобрался, токен получаю, отправляю запрос к сайту с токеном и получаю в ответ данные пользователя. Делал за этим не большим руководством: http://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/

Но вот в чем проблема, при указании в хедере неправильного токена (или токен время которого истекло), мене редиректит на страницу запроса логина. И тут я хотел было материться, ибо до того пробовал также на laravel/passport сделать и там тоже самое было. Суть в том, что должен возвращаться ответ JSON c указанием ошибки, вместо этого меня редиректит на сайт, я уже мислить нормально не могу, просто в нете статьи перечитываю. Пробовал создавать своих посредников и проверять в них, пробовал добавлять нечто подобное:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    try {
        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

и не только здесь, но схожий код писал и в посредник... Ну никак, не могу избавиться от этого. Плюс документации - как кот наплакал. Подскажите, что можно сделать. Может у вас есть какие-небудь ссилки на хорошие статьи по этому поводу или примеры работ как это делаеться (как на jwt-auth так и на laravel/passport, последний больше понравился, есть более-менее норм документация плюс я вижу где храняться токени и прочие данние - в базе, а как jwt работает не понимаю).
Прошу камнями не забрасывать, я новичок в этом деле, где-то 2 месяца изучаю ларавел, а с API меньше недели...
Если нужна еще какая-то инфа - готов предоставить.

Comment: Я так подозреваю что вся проблема в middleware auth, так как по умолчанию, если вы ломитесь на страницу где нужна авторизация а вы не авторизованы он вас редиректит

Comment: Попробуй тут  `Exceptions > Handler.php` поменять unauthenticated или добавь в заголовок запроса `Accept: application/json`

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо! Добавление Accept: application/json помогло! причем я вернулся на ветку где я тоже самое делал с помощью laravel/passport и там все отлично работает. А насчет этого "поменять unauthenticated" можно поподробнее? На всякий случай было бы хорошо знать))) Спасибо Вам еще раз!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы получить ответ в формате json во всех заголовках необходимо слать `Accept: application/json.`

Так же можно сменить логику, что делать в случае ошибки, если посмотреть на класс который расширяет `Exceptions > Handler.php` это будет класс

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler as ExceptionHandler
```

в нем есть метод:

```
protected function unauthenticated($request, AuthenticationException $exception)
{
    return $request->expectsJson()
           ? response()->json(['message' => $exception->getMessage()], 401)
                    : redirect()->guest(route('login'));
}
```

Его можно переопределить в вашем Handler.php и написать любую логику